# WPF chart controls

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

I am looking for a very simple WPF chart which should have a 2D graph and 
should have pan and zoom facilities .

Comment: If researching WPF charting, try our very small demo download for a quick experience of our speed, rendering quality, robustness, and user code. Yes, I've ran Gigasoft for 14+ years, talk to me, I'm here to help. [wpf charting](http://www.gigasoft.com/wpfchart.html)

Comment: The new Metro Charts are really good - see http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/ for details. They are targetting Windows 8 and .net 4.5, but you can get them to run on Windows 7 with .net 4. Take a look at http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/charting-with-wpf/ if you need a quick tutorial on how to get started.

Comment: Most of this options are out of date, I made this free project, maybe it helps others too https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Comment: why is this off topic? This was very helpful to me today.

Answer (score 190):

Free tools supporting panning / zooming:

- [Live Charts](https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/LiveCharts2)
- [ScottPlot](https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot)
- [DynamicDataDisplay](https://github.com/Microsoft/InteractiveDataDisplay.WPF) - a nice, open source data visualization library. Unfortunately it's not been updated since April 30, 2009.
- [OxyPlot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/)

Free tools without built in pan / zoom support:

- [WPF Toolkit](https://web.archive.org/web/20180111120841/http://wpf.codeplex.com:80/releases/view/40535). Supports most important 2D charts, you'll have to implement pan / zoom yourself.
- [WPF Toolkit Development Release](https://web.archive.org/web/20151017144834/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/delay/archive/2010/04/20/phone-y-charts-silverlight-wpf-data-visualization-development-release-4-and-windows-phone-7-charting-sample.aspx). Supports stacked charts, equivalent to the Silverlight version.

Paid tools with built in pan / zoom support:

- [SciChart WPF](https://www.scichart.com/wpf-chart-features/). Supports DirectX accelerated 2D & 3D charts, comes with zooming and panning, mouse-wheel with animation on zoom. ([See this blog post](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/win/current/Synchronizing%20Multiple%20Charts.html) on using zooming / panning across multiple charts)
- [Infragistics xamDataChart](https://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf/charts/data-chart#Overview). Supports most important 2D charts, zooming and panning. See [this blog article](https://www.infragistics.com/community/forums) on how to use zooming.
- [Telerik RadChart](https://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chartview.aspx?gclid=CMOpoaHD8pgCFQqF3goddzFT1w). Supports lots of 2D charts, has some support for zooming and panning, you might need to do a little work on that.
- [Visifire](https://visifire.com/). Supports lots of 2D charts and zooming without animation, might need to do some extra work for smoother zooming.(This service is no longer available)
- [DevExpress ChartControl](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Charting/). Supports most common [2D Series types](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/114223/controls-and-libraries/charts-suite/chart-control/series/2d-series-types), [zooming and panning (scrolling)](https://docs.devexpress.com/WPF/11234/controls-and-libraries/charts-suite/chart-control/zoom-scroll-and-rotate-the-chart/zoom-and-scroll-in-2d-xy-charts) operations can be performed using the mouse, keyboard, and touch gestures.
- [Syncfusion SfChart](https://www.syncfusion.com/wpf-controls/charts). Supports many [2D series types](https://web.archive.org/web/20160708125640/http://help.syncfusion.com:80/wpf/sfchart/series) and provides the [interactive zooming](https://help.syncfusion.com/wpf/charts/interactive-features/#zoom-and-pan) feature that supports the touch mode. Various zoom types are supported (mouse wheel, pinch, selection).

***Full Disclosure:*** I have been heavily involved in development of Visiblox, hence I know that library in much more detail than the others.

Comment: It appears that Visiblox is only free if you're happy to have watermarked charts, and Visifire is only a trial version.

Comment: @Basarat Ali: could you link an example? Can't find any example showing this off in their gallery.

Comment: notice the scrollbar has draggable handles ... you can use it to zoom the x axis as well as pan it : http://www.visifire.com/blog/2010/02/26/visifire-silverlight-and-wpf-charts-3-0-4-beta-released/ Another version added click zoom : http://www.visifire.com/blog/2010/04/09/visifire-silverlight-and-wpf-charts-3-0-6-beta-2-released/ Although both are X axis only ... hmmm maybe they don't have y axis zooming. Best to ask in their forum

Comment: There is something that vaguely resembles an X zoom. If you're looking to implement proper zooming and panning Visifire at the moment doesn't seem to have that out of the box.

Comment: Full disclosure, Gigasoft owner, new release now with WPF. Here's info and link to 7 meg demo that's a must see for anyone interested in wpf charting: [link](http://www.gigasoft.com/wpfchart.html)

Comment: `DynamicDataDisplay`(IDD) last commit is 5 days ago.

Comment: related: [Performance benchmarks of 8 WPF charts](https://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/24/wpf-charting-performance-comparisons-the-battle-continues.html) [2012]

Comment: your list is very good, but you have missed the Arction LightningChart in the paid components. it is the best realtime monitoring component for both wpf and winforms. also you have missed ZedGraph in the free tools. it has been the most useful component for hardware intefaces for years.

Comment: ScottPlot has a great example application to go with it. 70+releases, almost 5k commits and MIT Licensing.  https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot

Answer (score 69):

Another one is [OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com), which is an open-source cross-platform (WPF, Silverlight, WinForms, Mono) .Net plotting library.

Comment: Oxy plot is really good, but it didn´t was what I wanted so I made this, maybe it can help others too https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts

Answer (score 28):

[DynamicDataDisplay](http://www.codeplex.com/dynamicdatadisplay) is brilliant, zoom and pan built in and its free on CodePlex.

Comment: They are good but last time they updated was in 2009

Comment: I can attest to this. It's decent for rapidly putting together a chart. Documentation is basically non-existent though so you should expect to look for tutorials on the internet. Best tutorial I've looked at is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714591.aspx

Comment: @MrTelly can you tell me that can we use D3 charts with .NET 3.5 ?

Comment: @saad a long while since I used, and that was with .net 2.0. As you have the source it should just work, and if it doesn't it can be fixed. Let me know if you need a hand.

Answer (score 9):

You can get the Silverlight Chart Controls [running on WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2008/11/18/silverlight-chart-control-running-in-wpf.aspx), they're quite nice (and free).

Comment: As far as I know they don't come with zooming / panning out of the box though unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

The WPF Toolkit is available. It is free from CodePlex.

It can be downloaded [here](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117). 
There is some commentary [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The chart control in the WPF Toolkit has a horrible bug: it never forgets any of the data points. So if you try to implement a floating chart you will get out of memory after round about 3000 DataPoint-objects.
This bug has been reported to MS over a year ago but nobody seems to care...

Answer (score 5):

Sparrow Chart Toolkit a best opensource chart control for multiple platforms

-WPF
-Silverlight
-WinRT
-Windows phone
-Windows Forms
-Mono

https://sparrowtoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: Look very nice and works well. No documentation!

Answer (score 4):

[Visifire](http://www.visifire.com/wpf_charts.php/) supports wide range of 2D and 3D charts with zooming and panning functionality.

[image: Visifire Line chart with zooming]

Full Disclosure: I have been involved in the development of Visifire.

Answer (score 3):

[Code project article here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/swordfishcharts.aspx).

Commercial products:

1. [SoftwareFX](http://www.softwarefx.com/sfxNetProducts/ChartFX/WPF/)
2. [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx?gclid=CMOpoaHD8pgCFQqF3goddzFT1w)

I'm sure there are others

Comment: I've used SoftwareFX's ChartFx product and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

[aM Charts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/demo) are also making WPF Chart controls. Currently they only show off a pie chart, but they are set to provide new ones in short term.

Comment: amCharts for WPF are now out of beta and support most popular chart types like line, area, column, bar, pie, etc.

Comment: However, amCharts will have watermark on topleft corner unless you purchase the license.

Answer (score 2):

Also DevExpress have Charts (see [DevExpress.Com](http://devexpress.com/)).

Answer (score 2):

Try GraphIT from TechNewLogic, you can find it on CodePlex here: http://graphit.codeplex.com

**Full Disclosure:** I am the developer of GraphIT and owner of the developing company.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.