# WPF Graph control

Tags: wpf

I am a new bee in wpf. I want to implement a graph in my application using C#.net.
I try to implement chart , but chart have x,y coordinates & legents. I want to display only small graph, i don't want to display AxiesX,AxiesY points& Graph descryption.

What is the best & simple graph control in wpf, how i can implement in C#.net.

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here: http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535 and get the WPFToolKit

It includes charting controls that are basic, functional, and easy to use. Best of all, they're free.

It will add the System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization namespace to your project when you add WPFToolKit as a reference.

You can do it all in code-behind... if you really have to.  :)

Answer (score 1):

i have been using visifire and i really like them. Easy to use and look really nice. the have trial charts that you can try out but to use them it does cost money, but it isnt terribly expensive considering how much time you could spend creating your own charts.

http://www.visifire.com/