# How to add .NET 4.0 Chart controls to XBAP/ WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, xbap

Is there a way to add .NET 4.0 Chart controls in a WPF application?

I read this thread : 
[WPF chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)

But from the above thread I was unable to gather if the WPF Toolkit is stable.

But I was wondering if there is any other input on this? PLease help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the WPF Toolkit has been abandoned by Microsoft, and the latest release is full of bugs. The thread you link to seems pretty definitive.

Comment: Oh ! Thanks. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: None that I have experience with; I'd say go back and read through the suggestions in the thread you linked to.