# WPF chart control: OxyPlot documentation

Tags: wpf, charts

I'm looking for a simple, free charting control for WPF. After some reading (e.g. [WPF chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/q/577278/1356597)), I had a look at OxyPlot: http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/

It looks very promising and well done: did you ever use it? Can you suggest a place to find some additional reference (that on the website seems to be still incomplete)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started to use this library as well. Until now I like it.

About the documentation, I agree it is indeed quite poor. Probably the best you can do is to explore the code of the examples that you find in the project. I can say I could find all the code I need.

By the way the only small problem that I have had until now is visible in picture. It happens with a large number of points (e.g.. > 1000).

[image]

EDIT:

this problem happens when LineJoin is set to OxyPenLineJoin.Miter; 
it can be solved by

```
LineJoin = OxyPenLineJoin.Bevel;
```

or

```
LineJoin = OxyPenLineJoin.Round;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, up to now I was able to produce some charts by using the CTRL+ALT+C feature of the examples provided by the developer. But still I can't find out how (for example) keep the chart sync while the PlotModel get updated.

Comment: If I understand well, in the constructor of your view you need CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering. Then inside CompositionTarget_Rendering call youroxychart.RefreshPlot(true);