# Microsoft .NET Chart Controls for WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, charts, controls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)

I'm looking for a .NET Framework Chart Controls for WPF.

I've found this one : http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart

But it seems that it doesn't support WPF.

Is there anyone who already used .NET Chart Controls in a WPF Project ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with theses projects

- WPF Toolkit: http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535
- Visiblox: http://www.visiblox.com/
- Infragistics: http://www.infragistics.com/products/wpf-data-visualization/data-chart/#Overview

Answer (score 7):

You can embed mschart into WPF using WindowsFormsHost.

I have done this in an application because I found all of the WPF solutions I tried were not able to cope with the real time data of my system.