# chart and graph controls in visual studio 2012

Tags: graph, charts, controls

I have been developing windows phone 8 application in visual studio 2012. I need to use chart and graph control in my application. Can some one suggest me some effective solution for the same. Is there any way to add graph, chart controls in visual studio 2012 toolbox ?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the charting components in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls/4227432#4227432) WPF related question support WP8.