# how to bind collection to a grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Ok I have a way to achieve this

[image]

but I do way in c# like so

```
public partial class PlotTest
    {
        public PlotTest(double x, double y)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            PlotControl.Margin = new Thickness(x, y, 0, 0);
        }

        public void setPlot(List<double> tempSol)
        {
            double step = (tempSol.Max() - tempSol.Min()) / 10;

            for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
            {
                TextBlock rect = (TextBlock)PlotValue.Children[ctr];
                rect.Text = (ctr == 0) ? tempSol.Max().ToString("F") :
                            (ctr == 9) ? tempSol.Min().ToString("F") : 
                            (tempSol.Max() - ctr * step).ToString("F");
                rect.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Right;
                rect.FontSize = 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

since I do it with c# and I,m using wpf I would like to find a way to bind it to a collectionm precisely this one

```
 private List<double> tempsol = new List<double> {3.21, -5.41, -15.81, -21.69, -21.70, -12.60, -6.41, -0.06, 5.42, 13.32, 14.12, 7.55};
```

but since I'm new to wpf, xaml I'm really unsure how to do it and I can't find any solution that apply directly to my problem I could use some help thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`Grid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx) is merely one type of [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel(v=vs.110).aspx), however I don't think that it is the right one to select from in your situation.

At the core of things, what you want to do is visually display a sequence of values, of which they happen to be double values. When you want to visually display a sequence, you must look at an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol(v=vs.110).aspx) (or derivative of this class). From there, you can customize how each individual element is visually represented, and how the entire sequence of elements is also visually represented:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <custom:SomePanel />
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <!-- Some representation of each element -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Of course, here are some supplemental reading material if you decide to roll out your own `Panel`:

- Dr. Wpf - *P is for Panel*: http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/02/10/itemscontrol-p-is-for-panel/
- CodeProject - *Creating custom Panels*: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF
- Wpf Tutorial - *Custom Layout Panel*: http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html

---

Alternatively, you could use something that is already created out there: [WPF chart controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)