# Visual Studio 2013 WPF Toolbox greyed out Chart item

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am trying to create a chart in my WPF application. In the toolbox I right clicked and selected the Choose Items option. I then clicked on the .Net Framework Components tab & ticked the box which had the namespace System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.

After doing this I went to the Data section in the toolbox but all the menu items are greyed out including the Chart option I would like to use, why is this?

Comment: `System.Web.UI` does not sound like a WPF specific namespace. BTW it is strongly recommended that you forget the "toolbox" stuff and learn how to program properly in WPF by familiarizing yourself with XAML and XAML-related concepts such as `xmlns` and the like.

Comment: I think HighCore is right, this doesn't sound like a WPF control. Check out alternatives here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls

Comment: I do use XAML but just been trying to find a chart control. Once I have a chart control and had a look at it I would then use xaml. I just want a line chart & column chart. The assembly name given for this namespace is System.Web.DataVisualization.