# Building a logical tree for a custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, logical-tree

I'm working on a control that has an `ObservableCollection` as one of its `DependencyProperties`.  This property is set as the `DefaultProperty` for my control, so I can implicitly add items to the collection in XAML by constructing lines similar to the following:

```
<MyControl>
    <MyItem/>
    <MyItem/>
    <MyItem/>
</MyControl>
```

As far as I understand, the WPF engine builds the logical tree when it parses through the XAML.  Therefore, each `MyItem` should be a logical child of the `MyControl`.  Conversely, the `MyControl` should be the logical parent of each `MyItem`.

Well, apparently there is more to it.  Below is the code that I use to define the relationship above.  The custom control contains a `DependencyProperty` for the `ObservableCollection` and it is backed by a CLR-property.

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class MyControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Items", 
        typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>), 
        typeof(MyControl), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, OnItemsChangedProperty));

    [Category("MyControl")]
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyControl() : base()
    {   //Set a new collection per control, but don't destroy binding.
        SetCurrentValue(ItemsProperty, new ObservableCollection<MyItem>());
    }
}
```

From with the `MyItem` (which inherits `FrameworkContentElement`), I attempt to access its logical parent like so:

```
if (Parent is FrameworkElement)
{    //Re-Render the parent control.
    ((FrameworkElement)Parent).InvalidateVisual();
}
```

To my surprise, the parent control is never re-rendered.  This is because the `MyItem.Parent` property is null.  Why is this?

How can I instruct the WPF engine to know that `MyControl` should be the logical parent to `MyItem`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not trying to reinvent `Panel` or `ItemsControl`? Manually dealing with logical/visual children and re-rendering stuff isn't something you normally have to deal with in WPF, as it's all handled by the framework.

Comment: Nope, not reinventing either of those.  I'm making a graphing control that allows for multiple sets of lines to be placed.  Each set corresponds to a different item, and my custom control must be notified when to re-render.  I agree, this isn't a normal thing;  I'm authoring a very complex control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a chart control with multiple graphs, you're definitely in `ItemsControl` land. You may want to have a look at what you can build from `WPFToolkit` or one of the other tools listed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227432/1869660

*As for your actual question*, if you really need to add `MyItem`s to your logical tree manually, you need to call `AddLogicalChild()`, for example somewhere in your `OnItemsChangedProperty` event. There is an [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.addlogicalchild(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That did it.  I didn't know I needed to handle the adding/removing of logical children myself.  Thanks much! :)