# Chart Control for dynamic & actual line

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, charts, lineseries

I working a project with wpf in c#.. I want to use chart tools for graphics on the picture. Yellow line is reference position for purple (Actual) line. When Actual line touch reference line or when it cross the yellow line then I have to mark this touch point.(You can see an exmp. on picture). Of course same time I have to any action in programs.

How Can I do it with best easy way? 
Can I do it with C# WPF or another question I use which editor program for this chart?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF chart controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls)