# Adding chart control to WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, charts

I have made an app using WPF and coding in c# at VS 2017.

It contains many buttons and so on.

However, when I try to add charts in it I cant find the control in the toolbox.

I tried few things I have read as:

1) right click toolbox-> choose item -> chart... didnt work.

2) install blend SDK for .NET...didnt work

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: WPF do not have built-in chart, but you can use winfroms chart or use other libraries, go to [stack-answered-here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls), in each library there is usually instalation option

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to keep WPF , you have to use the drawing primitives

i have found a sample on my disk which draws sin and cos function:

Wpf sample:

```
<Window x:Class="DrawChart.SinCosChart"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Simple Chart" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5">
            <Canvas Name="chartCanvas" Width="250" Height="200" ClipToBounds="True"/>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace DrawChart
{
    public partial class SinCosChart : Window
    {
        private double xmin = 0;
        private double xmax = 6.5;
        private double ymin = -1.1;
        private double ymax = 1.1;
        private Polyline pl;
        public SimpleLineChart()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AddChart();
        }
        private void AddChart()
        {
            // Draw sine curve:
            pl = new Polyline();
            pl.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
            {
                double x = i / 5.0;
                double y = Math.Sin(x);
                pl.Points.Add(NormalizePoint(
                    new Point(x, y)));
            }
            chartCanvas.Children.Add(pl);
            // Draw cosine curve:
            pl = new Polyline();
            pl.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            pl.StrokeDashArray = new DoubleCollection(
                new double[] { 4, 3 });
            for (int i = 0; i < 70; i++)
            {
                double x = i / 5.0;
                double y = Math.Cos(x);
                pl.Points.Add(NormalizePoint(
                    new Point(x, y)));
            }
            chartCanvas.Children.Add(pl);
        }
        private Point NormalizePoint(Point pt)
        {
            Point result = new Point();
            result.X = (pt.X - xmin) *
                       chartCanvas.Width / (xmax - xmin);
            result.Y = chartCanvas.Height – (pt.Y - ymin) *
                chartCanvas.Height / (ymax - ymin);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```