# How to use observablehq/plot from .NET 5 app?

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, observablehq, clearscript

Our team intends to use JavaScript library [*observablehq/plot*](https://github.com/observablehq/plot) from an app written in C# and running on .NET 5. As a proof of concept, we were able to successfully use that library running in a separate process on [*Node.js*](https://nodejs.org/en/about/). The downside of this approach is that we would need to implement all data serialization and inter-process communication ourselves, and we would need to bundle *Node.js* in our app installer. We are looking for an alternative approach that would not require *Node.js*, but instead would directly host V8 JavaScript engine in our .NET app. Currently, we are considering using [*ClearScript*](https://github.com/microsoft/ClearScript) package for that. While we were able to successfully run simple JavaScript code using it, we discovered that *observablehq/plot* and its dependencies use some APIs that are present in *Node.js*, but are apparently unavailable in *ClearScript* out-of-the-box (it seems that *Node.js* implements some of those APIs in JavaScript, and some in C++). Making those implementations available to *ClearScript* running in .NET app looks like a significant task whose cost I cannot estimate at this point.

I would like to ask if anyone had to solve the same or similar problem, and what approach would you recommend? Is there an easy way to make all necessary APIs available to *observablehq/plot* running on *ClearScript*? Should I consider hosting Chromium/Edge browser engine in the .NET app instead? I haven’t yet tried this, but I assume it is possible because my understanding (correct me if I’m wrong) is that [*WebView2*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) control can be used in WPF apps running on .NET, and it is implemented using *Chromium* and V8 JavaScript engine. Is there any other approach you can recommend?

---

*Update:* The app GUI is built on [Avalonia](https://avaloniaui.net/) and [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp). It is possible that eventually we will choose another charting library, perhaps, one not written in JavaScript. But my task at hand is specifically to investigate whether and how we can use JavaScript libraries in our app, taking *observablehq/plot* as an example, and investigate its features and performance characteristics.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately most JavaScript libraries assume a web or Node.js environment and won't work elsewhere without modification or equivalent APIs.

Comment: Are you using Xamarin Forms or Blazor webassembly for your app? i suppouse this is a mobile app? Desktop App? explain better this point please.

Comment: The app GUI is built on Avalonia and SkiaSharp. I updated the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building a **WPF** desktop app you should try a WPF based chart library that feats your needs.

Open source libraries:

1. [OxyPlot](https://github.com/oxyplot)
2. [InteractiveDataDisplay](https://predictionmachines.github.io/InteractiveDataDisplay/)
3. [ScottPlot](https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot) support pan and zoom.

Paid libraries:

1. [Telerik RadChart](https://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/chart.aspx?gclid=CMOpoaHD8pgCFQqF3goddzFT1w)
2. [DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Charting/)

More info about [WPF charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577278/wpf-chart-controls) in this post.

If you are using **Blazor WebAssembly**:

Use [jsRuntime](https://romansimuta.com/posts/how-to-call-isolated-javascript-code-in-net-5-0-blazor-projects-with-jsobjectreference/) and JSObjectReference to import and call your Javascript observablehp library.

If you are using **Xamarin.Forms** the best professional library out there is probably SyncFusion:

1. [Syncfusion Charts](https://www.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ui-controls/xamarin-charts)

**Update**:

Avalonia Framework only will support this through a webview / embedded browser as you stated above. Here you have 3 options:

1. [Cefnet](https://github.com/CefNet/CefNet) is a .NET CLR binding for the Chromium Embedded Framework
2. [CefGlue](https://gitlab.com/joaompneves/cefglue) same than above
3. [WebView Avaloria-CefGlue](https://github.com/OutSystems/WebView)

For more usefull tools and libraries to use with Avalonia please refer to [Awesome Avalonia](https://github.com/AvaloniaCommunity/awesome-avalonia).